# How hard disk interfaces with microprocessor?

Tags: io, operating-system

I learned in assembly that to read/write in hard disk we need to use interrupt 13h and give parameters like cylinder no.,sector no. etc to specific registers. I want to know why we need to give specific parameter to specific registers like cl=sector no. , ch=cylinder no.? . I know they all are general purpose register and no hardware implementation is there.

Comment: See http://wiki.osdev.org/PCI_IDE_Controller

Comment: I have checked no relevant answer

Comment: The article I have linked shows how hard disk interfaces with the microprocessor through the hardware component called IDE controller. The article shows how microprocessor "_talks_" to the controller. What else would you like to know?